# Use a Mid-2010 21" iMac as a monitor for a Windows PC with MiniDP port

Tags: external-display, imac, mini-displayport

I've got an old iMac (mid-2010 model) but I don't want to use it directly. I appreciate its display and audio so it sounds good if it can be turned into a simple monitor. My primary Windows 10 PC is capable of outputting video through <s>HDMI</s> and Mini DisplayPort. I checked the back of the iMac and found a MiniDP (with an icon that looks like <kbd>|□|</kbd>). I'm not sure whether that's a MiniDP or a Thunderbolt. How can I do this? Hardware solution is preferred.

Comment: I would assume the port at the Mac is an _output_, not an _input_.

Comment: @Aganju So you mean **no solution**?

Comment: I am not a hardware specialist. I'm sure simply plugging a cable in will not be enough, but maybe they're ways.

Comment: Even if it supported Target Display Mode, the iMac would have to be fully powered on when using it as a display. That’s a tremendous waste of power.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible.

Only the 27" iMacs from that period were capable of Target Display Mode, on all other models that port is an output only.

See Apple KB - [Use your iMac as a display with Target Display Mode](https://support.apple.com/HT204592)